# TinyMCE can't resize Youtube videos embeded on Plone 4.3.10rc1

Tags: tinymce, plone

I've upgraded to Products.TinyMCE 1.3.25 on my Plone 4.3.10rc1 installation. When I add an embeded video in edition mode, I can't resize the frame. It occurs only with Youtube videos, but it works fine with Vimeo, por instance.

I have tried an answer in https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/3614?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container, but without answer yet.

Any issues about that? Thanks in advance...

Comment: For best results, please post your Plone questions in our forum at https://community.plone.org

Comment: It's done! Thanks Kim... I'm waiting by a staff member review.

Comment: It's a community forum, so it's all volunteers. (unless you hire paid help at say plone.com/providers) :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot resize the video because it's dimensions are being explicitly set by the media plugin.

I am on TinyMCE version 3.5.12 (2016-10-31). I tried to debug the JavaScript. And in the media plugin, there is part of code, which compares URL with some pattern, and if the URL is YouTube, than it sets the size to exactly 425x350.
The part of code is this:

```
// YouTube Embed
if (src.match(/youtube\.com\/embed\/\w+/)) {
    data.width = 425;
    data.height = 350;
    data.params.frameborder = '0';
    data.type = 'iframe';
    setVal('src', src);
    setVal('media_type', data.type);
}
...
setVal('width', data.width || (data.type == 'audio' ? 300 : 320));
setVal('height', data.height || (data.type == 'audio' ? 32 : 240));
```

I don't understand the purpose of the code yet, but clearly, it is there for purpose, not just some broken code.
Maybe it is meant as setting the dimensions for the first time, as initial size, but it sets them always.